# User email notification when they upload a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am running a custom wordpress function where a user can upload a custom post type to my website.

I am looking for a plugin or solution to be able to send the individual user an email confirmation that they have created a new custom post.

It would need to send an email to the correct user when it detects they have created a post.

Is there anything that can do this?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0):

It depends how they doing the upload.  If you are using a forms plugin, it may have the functionality built-in or via an add-on.    There are a number of suggestions on the internet such as
https://gravitywiz.com/notify-author-when-post-is-published/ or 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113019/when-a-user-creates-a-post-pending-send-a-confirmation-link-that-allows-them

Comment: Thankyou for your response.
I'm using a forms plugin but it doesnt have any support for email notifications to the user who uploads.
So I need to hack into it and manually create the email notifications

Comment: Would Gravity Forms be able to fill this role do you think?

I also found this plugin but unsure whether it would work? Better Notifications for WordPress